# Customize struts based application to consume spring boot microservice (jSP alone)

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

What is the best design for the below situation.

- have an monloith app runs on struts and jsp.
  -- information show in JSP like dropdown values are part of monoloith.
  -- This information is going to come from some other microservice and it should be shown in the same jsp and controlled based on feature whether to show old dropdown vs new dropdown.

My thoughts were to use a js library included in the JSP which will show existing jsp dropdown vs the js library which will call rest api to get those values.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. Seems pretty straight-forward, though; you either get them from your app, or you get them from somewhere else. You can get them from somewhere else on the client side, or from within your existing app. *shrug*

Comment: To avoid growing monolith app, idea is to do bear minimum changes over there and it gets data from external source. So the question would be what is the best practice to invoke external application from a JSP.

Comment: There is no “best practice”, it depends.